# Making Horizontal Distance lines IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, location, computer-vision

I wanted to show an overlay over camera view and for that I have to show horizontal lines that show distance from the current location. I have simplified this that the lines will show only the distance in some x meters units. Such that each next arc/line shows points the next x meters away.

It must be something like this:
 [image]

So I know that this can be achieved by using lines on the horizontal bottom and applying some AFFINE transformation on it containing rotation and displacement. 
Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just draw the arcs with appropriate radii!

Comment: Use the UIBezierPath class.  Specifically, this method:  bezierPathWithArcCenter:radius:startAngle:endAngle:clockwise:  here's a link to the docs:  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBezierPath_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIBezierPath/bezierPathWithArcCenter:radius:startAngle:endAngle:clockwise: